# Getting unexpected Int value when passing value to powershell function as parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call an API with a powershell script to return a paginated dump of all users and there values. I get a page count which populates the number of pages I need to call. I put that value into a for loop and the int increases with each run of the loop. In the middle of the Loop when I pass $I into my function the Function gets 0 instead of the number being passed in.

```
Function GetUserOnPage ([string]$AccessToken, [int]$I)
{
    write-host $I 'the loaded page'
    $Header=$null
    $Header = @{}; 
    $Header.Add("Authorization",'Bearer '+ $AccessToken)
    $URL='https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page='+ $I
    write-host $URL

    $request = Invoke-webrequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get -uri $URL -Headers $Header -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    $JsonParameters = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $request.content

    $memberList = $JsonParameters.member_list

    return $memberList
}


Function Execute()
{
    BuildDataTable

    $accessToken = LogintoBI
    $pageCount = GetUserPageCount($accessToken)
    $pages = $pageCount

    For($I = 1; $I -le $pages; $I++)
    {
        Write-host 'counting up' $I
        $members = GetUserOnPage($accessToken, [int]$I)
        write-host 'checking' $I

        Foreach($member in $members)
        {
            AddMemberToTable($member)
        }
    }         
}

Execute
```

Below is the returns i'm putting in with the write-host to check my values

> > counting up 1 
> >     0 the loaded page
> >     https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page=0
> >     checking 1
> >     counting up 2
> >     0 the loaded page
> >     https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page=0
> >     checking 2
> >     counting up 3
> >     0 the loaded page
> >     https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page=0
> >     checking 3
> >     counting up 4
> >     0 the loaded page
> >     https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page=0
> >     checking 4
> >     counting up 5
> >     0 the loaded page
> >     https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page=0
> >     checking 5
> >     counting up 6
> >     0 the loaded page
> >     https://mycompany.myapplication.com/api/member?page=0
> >     checking 6

Comment: Just get rid of the brackets when calling the function: $members = GetUserOnPage $accessToken [int]$I

Comment: i tried this and i got the exact same result. also tried with and without the comma.

Comment: as Owain Esau pointed out, you are not passing in what you THINK you are passing in. [*grin*] you are passing in an array, not two items. to fix that = remove the parens AND remove the comma. ///// to avoid this really common error in the future, use the parameter names when you call the function. this `GetUserOnPage -AccessToken $accessToken -I $I` would have let you avoid that error. [*grin*] ///// also, PLEASE do not use the same $VarName in a function that you are using outside the function. it makes it far too easy to confuse what goes where.

Comment: Declaring the parameter names solved this. i was a little bit confused on why i absolutely had to do that to make it work as I've never had to in the past but it seems to have resolved this issue. Thank you!

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... and the habit of using full parameter names has helped me avoid foot-gunning myself more than once! [*grin*]

Comment: **In PowerShell, functions are invoked _like console (terminal) programs_** - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# _methods_ - `foo(arg1, arg2)` - see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).  
If you accidentally use `,` to separate your arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a function sees as a _single_ argument.  
To help avoid accidental use of method syntax, you can use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below lines and it should clear up as well.

```
GetUserOnPage($accessToken, [int]$I)
```

Should be

```
GetUserOnPage $accessToken $I
```

**Changed answer because of comment**

Comment: I set I to read-host and then i had to enter a user prompt to continue. the prompt was automatically a string for some reason even though it is casted as an int and i input a number and it didn't allow another input after that. I've set it to 1 instead of 0 because in the API call i need to call page 1 first.